# C# Sorting a list of class objects

Tags: c#

I'm trying to sort a list in descending order of the 'score' variable.  How would I do this?
This is the code I used to set up the list:

```
          private void LeaderboardScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      //GETTING VARIABLES FOR THE CLASS OBJECT
      using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(".\\InputInfo.bin"))
      using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, true))
      {
          string line;
          while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null) ;
      }
      var lines = File.ReadLines(".\\InputInfo.bin");
      foreach (var line in lines)
      {
          string[] words = line.Split(); //Splits the line into seperate words, and puts them into an array called 'words'
          string name = words[0]; // Makes the first word the name
          string age = words[1]; //Makes the second word the age
          string gender = words[2];//Makes the third word the gender
          int score = Convert.ToInt32(words[3]);//Makes the forth word the score

          //SETTING UP THE LIST
          List<Player> players = new List<Player>(); 
          players.Add(new Player(name, age, gender, score));
      }
  }
```

THANKS!

Comment: first, take a less ambitious task of producing a list of players

Comment: have you tried to google this question ?

Comment: `stirng[] words = line.Split();` - that won't even compile.....and what's with `while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null);`?

Comment: Apologies. Tim the string[] words = line.Split(); seems to compile fine for me. And the while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null); was a mistake on my part which unfortunately I only noticed after I posted this question!

Comment: And yes I tried to google it, but couldn't find anything that helped me.

Comment: What's up with the List you declare again on every iteration over lines...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the [`OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) statement:

```
players = players.OrderBy(x => -x.Score).ToList();
```

By using a minus (`-`) - I assume score is a numerical value - you reverse the order.

You however made an **error** by constructing a `new List<Player>();` each time in your `foreach` loop so the list won't store the previous items. You should construct the `List<Player>` **before** entering the `foreach` loop and ordering it **after** the `foreach` loop.

Comment: You miss it :) "descending order" :)

Comment: @Sharped: modified by a minus so the two answers are still a bit different ;).

Comment: What about `score==0` :)

Comment: @EZI: in both sorting algorithm's they will behave the same... What is the supposed difference? After all this uses *comparison sort*. If I recall correctly what `OrderByDescending` does is constructing a reverse comparator (`-a` with `a` the answer of the original comparison).

Comment: @CommuSoft for `1,0,5` orderbydesc would return `5,1,0` but orderby `0,1,5`

Comment: @EZI: you forgot the minus (as noted in the answer), so the keys on which you sort are `-1,0,-5` resulting in `-5,-1,0` and the corresponding values are `5,1,0`. This [link](https://code.google.com/p/edulinq/source/browse/src/Edulinq/OrderByDescending.cs?r=5c5496546fb25988001f643a0c3a253f675af658) shows that the `OrderByDescending` is implemented in function of `OrderBy`...

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Linq;

players = players.OrderByDescending(i => i.Score).ToList();
```

Since you seems a little newbie at linq, here's an "optimized version"

```
lines.Select(line => 
  {
      string[] words = line.Split(); //Splits the line into seperate words, and puts them into an array called 'words'
      string name = words[0]; // Makes the first word the name
      string age = words[1]; //Makes the second word the age
      string gender = words[2];//Makes the third word the gender
      int score = Convert.ToInt32(words[3]);//Makes the forth word the score
      return new Player(name, age, gender, score);
  }).OrderByDescending(i => i.Score).ToList();
```

It avoid two list instantiations, and two loops over the whole set.

Answer (score 1):

While Linq is syntactically shiny, it is a bit wasteful.  The final .ToList() is creating a copy the list.
One of many non-Linq solutions is to pass a custom comparison function into Sort(...)

```
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        List<Player> players = new List<Player>();
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            // Fill your players list
        }

        players.Sort(ComparePlayersDescending);
    }

    public int ComparePlayersDescending(Player p1, Player p2)
    {
        int scoreDiff = p2.Score - p1.Score;
        if (scoreDiff != 0)
            return scoreDiff;
        else
            return p2.Name.CompareTo(p1.Name);
    }
```

Just for my own curiosity I ran the Linq method and this older one and measured the memory allocated on a list of 50,000 simple player objects.  You can either have efficiency or small code but not both :)

- players.Sort() allocated 8,192 bytes.
- players.OrderByDescending allocated 1,857,296 bytes.

  ```
      GC.Collect();
      long memCur = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
      //players = players.OrderByDescending(i => i.Score).ToList();
      players.Sort(ComparePlayersDescending);
      long memNow = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
      MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Total Memory: {0} {1}, diff {2}", memCur, memNow, memNow - memCur));
  ```